# java.sql.SQLException: Table 'QRTZ_TRIGGERS' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: java, tomcat

When starting Tomcat 5.5.26 instance on RHEL 3.4 AS, I am getting this error message:

```
2010-09-15 12:34:15,415 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].
[localhost].[/srs].[login-info]] - <Allocate exception for servlet login-info>
org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See
nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: Table 
'QRTZ_TRIGGERS' is marked as crashed and should be repaired [See nested exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Table 'QRTZ_TRIGGERS' is marked as crashed and should be 
repaired]] at 
g.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:493)`
```

How do I repair this?

Incidentally, this error under Tom Cat was for a Bioinformatics application called "SRS" by BioWisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself. The problem was not with Tomcat but with the application that was running underneath it. The application was using a MySQL database that had crashed due to a disk full condition. Repairing the table didn't help, so a new database had to be created. Luckily, this was easy.